# Python vs Javascript MD5 different for big numbers

Tags: javascript, python, md5, modulo

I have the following code in Python:

```
port_name = 'test-PR-2092'
print int(hashlib.md5(port_name).hexdigest(), 16) % 10000
// 353
```

In Javascript, I am using the crypto library to try to do the same thing (I do not have control over the python code so I need to keep that the same):

```
parseInt(
  crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update('test-PR-2092')
    .digest('hex'),
  16
) % 10000
// 4160
```

Javascript yields a much different result.

Looking at the int's, they are very similar except that Javascript is in scientific notation.

```
Python: 158458604564589336383831436621974090353
Javascript: 1.5845860456458934e+38
```

Does anyone know where this discrepancy comes from?

Edit: Solved my own problem, and not a duplicate because no one has recommended BigInteger in any question I have seen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python vs Javascript floating point arithmetic giving very different answers. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974625/python-vs-javascript-floating-point-arithmetic-giving-very-different-answers-wh)

Comment: Javascript doesn't have ints.

Comment: Javascript has one or the other surprise when doing calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found, BigInteger can take a hex value directly instead of first converting to an int.

```
const portHash = BigInteger(
    crypto
      .createHash('md5')
      .update('test-PR-2092')
      .digest('hex'),
    16
  )
    .mod(10000)
    .valueOf();
// 353
```

The answer is now the same as python.

Here is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer